# posting vue data back to the server

Tags: vue.js

I want to post an object back to my api, when i console.log the object it is containing lots of getters/setters and an observer object as well as my data. the data im going to post back is an object on the vue component data. My question is can i just post the object back with all these extra stuff or do i need to do something similar to when i have used knockout - there i would have similar issue with posting an observable so we would use ko util method toJson before sending as this would strip off the ko specific stuff. Is there something similar in vue?

Comment: ok i think i have it sussed if i just use json.stringify

Comment: I'm using `axios` and I'm sending vue component data, and it's only sending properties without methods. You didn't provide any code sample or mention which library you use for ajax calls, so I can't confirm 100% that it would be the same case for you.

Comment: Best way is to do the ajax call with the component data that you want to send and to inspect devtools network panel to see what is being sent to server.